# How to send selected logs to a logstash output

Tags: logstash

I am upgrading from logstash-1.1.3 to logstash-1.3.3.
The problem is, that tags and fields configuration that were there in 1.1.3 are deprecated in version 1.3.3. These allowed to send only those events to the output which had given tags or contained given fields.

I just want to know what replaces these in logstash-1.3.3. How do I get the same functionality of sending selected events to an output. I don't want to send all the events to an output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use if statement to do this.

```
output {
    if [type] == "tech" {
         stdout{}
    }
}
```

[This page](http://logstash.net/docs/1.3.3/configuration) has the introduction about how to configure.